# Incorporate combobox from a userform to multiple sheets based on values provided

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm a bit stuck with this part.

I have created a userform with different sections. First section will ask for Part# the userform will search in column A if the part exists if it doesn't it will add it to the last row available. Second section is a combobox selecting a month to add a value to (Columns C,N,O,P,Q). Next section is the value amount given to the part based on which month is selected. And the next section is where I'm stuck in the warehouse section I want to select a warehouse this references the tabs I created "Elkhart", "Tennessee" etc. I want to be able to add the part in the active sheet which is the "main" and also based on warehouse combobox option to add it to the last row of the tab.

> Ex. Part:Bob
>
> Month:Current
>
> Add:200
>
> Warehouse:Elkhart East

*This will add **Bob** to "**Main**" tab in the lastrow, however will add it to "**Elkhart East**" tab in the last row* too.

```
Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()

Dim irow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim iCol As String
Dim C As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim value As Long
Dim NewPart As Boolean
Set ws = Worksheets("Main")
Set wsE = Worksheets("Elkhart East")
Set wsT = Worksheets("Tennessee")
Set wsA = Worksheets("Alabama")
Set wsN = Worksheets("North Carolina")
Set wsP = Worksheets("Pennsylvania")
Set wsT = Worksheets("Texas")
Set wsW = Worksheets("West Coast")

Set C = ws.Range("A7:A1048576").Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If C Is Nothing Then
'find first empty row in database
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    irow = lastRow + 1
    NewPart = True
Else
'find row where the part is
    irow = ws.Cells.Find(What:=Me.PartTextBox.value, SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    NewPart = False
End If
'check for a part number
If Trim(Me.PartTextBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Part Number"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.MonthComboBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.MonthComboBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Month"
  Exit Sub
End If

If Trim(Me.AddTextBox.value) = "" Then
  Me.AddTextBox.SetFocus
  MsgBox "Please Enter A Value To Add Or Substract"
  Exit Sub
End If



Select Case MonthComboBox.value

    Case "Current Month"

        iCol = "C"

    Case "Current Month +1"

        iCol = "N"

    Case "Current Month +2"

        iCol = "O"

    Case "Current Month +3"

        iCol = "P"

    Case "Current Month +4"

        iCol = "Q"

End Select

**Select Case warehousecombobox.value
    Case "Elkhart East"
        iCol = wsE And irow
    Case "Tennessee"
        iCol = wsT And irow
    Case "Alabama"
        iCol = wsA And irow
    Case "North Carolina"
        iCol = wsN And irow
    Case "Pennsylvania"
        iCol = wsP And irow
    Case "Texas"
        iCol = wsT And irow
    Case "West Coast"
        iCol = wsW And irow
    End Select
value = Cells(irow, iCol).value**
With ws


  .Cells(irow, iCol).value = value + CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)


End With

If NewPart = True Then
    ws.Cells(irow, "A").value = Me.PartTextBox.value
End If


If NewPart = True Then
 ws.Cells(irow, "C").value = Me.AddTextBox.value
End If



'clear the data
Me.PartTextBox.value = ""
Me.MonthComboBox.value = ""
Me.AddTextBox.value = ""
Me.PartTextBox.SetFocus
Me.warehousecombobox.value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub MonthComboBox_Change()

End Sub
Private Sub Warehousecombobox_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Empty NameTextBox
 PartTextBox.value = ""

'Empty PhoneTextBox
 AddTextBox.value = ""

'Empty DinnerComboBox

'Fill DinnerComboBox
With MonthComboBox
     .AddItem "Current Month"
     .AddItem "Current Month +1"
     .AddItem "Current Month +2"
     .AddItem "Current Month +3"
     .AddItem "Current Month +4"

End With

With warehousecombobox
    .AddItem "Elkhart East"
    .AddItem "Tennessee"
    .AddItem "Alabama"
    .AddItem "North Carolina"
    .AddItem "Pennsylvania"
    .AddItem "Texas"
    .AddItem "West Coast"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here ? iCol = wsE And irow ? You set the colum to "worksheet and number" ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo this was my way of trying to use Worksheet "Elkhart East" and add it to the last row available.

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe i don't get your code, but i think you want something like this:

```
**Select Case warehousecombobox.value
Case "Elkhart East"
    wSheet = wsE 
...

wSheet.Range(iCol & iRow).value =  CLng(Me.AddTextBox.value)
```

Comment: This is giving me a object doesn't support this object or method and it highlights the case

Comment: this is your case ^^ maybe you should remove the ** and complete the case (thats what ... means)